# Android: How to setup a connection between two mobile devcies (Wi-Fi or network)

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am developing a game app where I am using Facebook SDK login button to retrieve the friend list. I want to send an invite to challenge their peers on the app. So the app receives a request from someone that they want to be challenged.

I do not want to use the request Dialog that uses facebook notifications. I want my own app to receive the notification and notify the user for incoming challenge.

I did some research and I could use the NSD but unfortunately it only allows you to connect to people on the same network. I want to be able to connect to friends from far away. I heard you can use emails but I have not found any documentation.

If you can point me to the right direction I really appreciate it.

Comment: would your notification be received in the facebook app or inside your application ?

Comment: @hars inside the application

Comment: what you are asking requires a server that will act as the middle man between 2 devices over the internet

Comment: @DanielMendel Yes, that is correct. The NSD is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

ok i suggest the below approach for what you are trying to achieve, use facebook sdk to get the user friend data, there will be an id and name in the response. you can use this facebook id to give people a unique id in your system. when people are wanting to challenge their friends you use their id from facebook friendlist and lookup in your system if these friends have registered/ install your application. if so you send a notification to them if not may be you suggest them to send them a email or sms with a uri to ask them to install the application. Try the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to play around with the data you can get from the Graph API.

Comment: @hard This is exactly what I want to do but there's no documentation to how to send notification to the person you want to challenge and connect . Do you know how to?

Comment: to do this notification I came across GCM service cloud messaging to send notification. However I will need to set up a server network connection to connect them. Is there any particular methods I can use?

Comment: yes you are correct you would need GCM for sending out notifications. To connect people realtime you would have to create websockets, which is one approach. socket.io can help you setup websockets. There are other third party providers which provide realtime sync of data. such as pubnub(https://www.pubnub.com/),firebase(https://www.firebase.com/) pubnub can also help you with notification. I would recommend reading.

Comment: I've been attempting to setup the push notification using GCM following this sample I found https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart . However on the Mainactivity file I added mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver inside onSuccess method. I get an error for startService(intent). It says it cannot resolve. Not sure what I did wrong.  I placed OnResume and OnStop methods outside. This was the only thing I found that did not uses php

Comment: I resolve the startService issue. How do I call the sendNotification. I randomly found GcmSender.java which I placed it in Lib folder from the link I provided above this comment. There is no proper documentation for this.

Comment: it is a little tough to help you like this probably you can set up some git repo where i can pitch in.

Comment: you can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488528/send-push-notification-using-gcm?noredirect=1#comment52882725_32488528